# Is Ubuntu 12.04 still vulnerable to the GHOST bug?

Tags: 12.04

The [GHOST](https://www.qualys.com/company/newsroom/news-releases/usa/2015-01-27-qualys-releases-security-advisory-ghost-vulnerability-linux-systems/) vulnerability was announced this week.

I've got a system that's running Ubuntu 12.04 appears to be vulnerable.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

ldd --version

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.15-0ubuntu10.10) 2.15
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

According to the link I provided, it was fixed between version 2.17 - 2.18.  I appear to be on 2.15.  I assume it's not been fixed by the Ubuntu team.  Can it be? it's such a major update.  Do I need to do a dist-upgrade?  I haven't seen any announcements or information for those running precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been fixed in 2.15 with the latest update.

```
$ apt-get changelog libc6

eglibc (2.15-0ubuntu10.10) precise-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: buffer overflow in __nss_hostname_digits_dots
    - debian/patches/any/CVE-2015-0235.diff: fix overflow in
      nss/digits_dots.c
    - CVE-2015-0235

 -- Steve Beattie <...>  Tue, 20 Jan 2015 13:22:12 -0800
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured out it wasn't vulnerable with a little c check program.  Turns out the update fixes it.  It'd be nice if Ubuntu posted such stuff on a feed on their main website.